# PHP Update API php://input returning unexpected response

Tags: php, insert-update

I am creating an API to update. When I call the API in Postman, I get  a strange response when I `var_dump` what I am to get.

Here is my code:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

And here is response I see on Postman

```
string(272) "----------------------------065126822322612777394821
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

382
----------------------------065126822322612777394821
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"

Created
----------------------------065126822322612777394821--
"
```

I am not sure what this response really means, I have tried searching but with no concrete results. Also, how do I get the values passed from params in Postman?

Comment: I think this is the raw input from a form submission. Why not try `var_dump($_REQUEST);` instead of looking at `php://input`? See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request

Comment: The request doesn't contain JSON, so decoding it as such won't work. It seems to be in the multipart/form-data-format.

Comment: @M.Eriksson they're not var dumping the json deciode `$data` they're var dumping `php://input`.  OP try var dumping `$data`.  Might be the same.

Comment: @AbraCadaver `they're not var dumping the json deciode $data they're var dumping php://input`...I think M.Eriksson knows that - otherwise how did they determine that the input data isn't JSON? That's exactly what the dump of $data shows. Therefore the attempt to decode it which follows would make no sense. I'm not sure what your issue with that comment is, it's completely logical :-)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php: _"`php://input` is not available in POST requests with enctype="multipart/form-data" if `enable_post_data_reading` option is enabled."_ - so I suppose that option must be enabled on your system, otherwise `php://input` should not have contained anything to begin with, in this case. (Having that option enabled is rather unusual, because then PHP will not parse the request body, and not populate $_POST & $_FILES. There are situations in which that might be wanted, but one should know what one was doing then.)